# Lagging after render in Movie Maker?

Tags: windows

I took a break from video editing for a while, but then I decided to come back and start again. However, every time I rendered the video, the clips suddenly wouldn't follow up with the music correctly, but when I check them back in WMM, they're perfectly lined up. I don't know what's happening since I've never had any issue before. Does anyone know what to do?
PS: I'm using the newest version of Windows Movie Maker.

Answer (score 1):

Could you tell me your input specifics. Because if the input was 60fps, there may be some problems if you render with standard settings, I once had this problem.

If you want to solve that, just click on save movie and scroll down till you see "create custom settings", then set the frame rate to 30fps, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ive had this problem for a while and finally found a solution. It seems that Windows Movie Maker has trouble previewing mp3 audio files and therefore previews at a lag. I fixed this issue by replacing the mp3 audio file with a wav file.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess (and it is a total guess) is that things are actually lagging when you are viewing it unrendered. If the video is playing out on a delay from when the audio should actually be playing, you would have aligned it wrong and then when you output and if makes an accurate playback, you find that the audio is coming before the video.

Most probably the issue is related to the video input.  If it is particularly large or difficult to read the video, WMM may not be able to keep up and will start lagging (you'd also probably notice a stutter when playing back, but maybe not).  I would try transcoding the videos to an easier to use format and try again or, preferably if possible, switch to something better than Windows Movie Maker that is worth exactly what you pay for it (nothing).